# How generate prime numbers in func

Tags: swift

I want to generate a set of infinity prime numbers. I'm using two functions. The first function checks whether the number is prime and gives the value of boolean. The second function, through the while status, twists the value of i and determines is the simple number with first func, then appends it to the set. But not wanna work. I think maybe my while condition incorrect?  while Int.max - 1 != i should the condition be different?

```
func checkPrime(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
        var i = 2
        while number / 2 >= i {
            if number % i == 0 {
                return false
            }
            i += 1
        }
        return true
    }

    func getPrimeInfinity() -> Set<Int> {

        var prime: Set = [1, 2, 3]
        var i = 3

        while Int.max - 1 != i {
            if checkPrime(i) {
                prime.insert(i)
            }
            i += 1
        }
        return prime
    }
```

Comment: Int.max is too large for this loop

Comment: `Int.max - 1` is `2^63 - 2 = 9223372036854775806`, so your loop will *never* terminate due to time *and* memory limitations. And note that this is an extremely inefficient way to compute all primes in a range. You should research for “sieving methods” instead, for example the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Nitpick: `1` is not a prime.

Comment: `2^(77,232,917) − 1` is the state of the art and it trumps Int.max

Comment: Here is a [library](https://github.com/dankogai/swift-prime) that you may find interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding prime numbers is a compute-intensive operation. There are multiple PHD theses on this subject.

You can't find all primes up to Int.max with a naive approach like yours. In fact I doubt if you can do it in your lifetime on a normal Mac, even with the best of algorithms.